# Custom Section Title View for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In some apps such as Cool Iris, LiveShare, i see them using custom views for their plain UITableView section titles.  Is there a way to replace the standard section title bar with a custom view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088257/uitableview-custom-header-title-view-doesnt-show/16687039#16687039

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to customize the look of your section header, there are two methods you will probably want to use.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

These are both found in the [UITableView delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  The first will let you create a custom view to display as your section header.  The second just makes sure you get the size you want for it so that your view doesn't get cut off

Comment: A bit off the topic, why apple put them into UITableViewDelegate, instead of UITableViewDataSource. Thx

Comment: @ThinkChris Because they have nothing to do with the DataSource.