# UITableView: custom header title view doesn't show

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios5

I want to display a table with custom header titles.
The `table view` is attached to a `controller class` that implements the `tableview delegate` and data source protocols but is not a subclass of `UIViewController` because the table is a subview to be displayed above another tableview.

some snippets of my code:
The tableview is created programmatically:

```
    _myListView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

[_myListView setDataSource:self.myListController];
[_myListView setDelegate:self.myListController];
[_myListView setBackgroundColor:darkBackgroundColor];
```

where myListController is a strong property in the class.

For the number of rows in sections:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    …
    return count;    
}
```

The number of sections:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [someDelegate sectionCount];
}
```

For the custom Header View:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView* headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, SectionHeaderHeight)];
    UILabel* sectionHeaderTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 3, 300, 24)];

    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    sectionHeaderTitle.text = [self myTitleForHeaderInSection:section];
    sectionHeaderTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    sectionHeaderTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

   [headerView addSubview:sectionHeaderTitle];

    return headerView;
}
```

For the custom headerViewHeight (as required since iOS5):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ( [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] > 0) {
        return SectionHeaderHeight;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Sadly, the tableview does not display any section headers just as if I would return nil. 
However, I have checked with a breakpoint, that the code actually returns an UIView.

Everything else works fine.

What am I missing? PLease, don't hesitate to make me feel ashamed of my self.

Comment: Why can’t you set a background color for your ‘headerView’ and check, it is visible? Edit:* And also for the ‘sectionHeaderTitle’ label...

Comment: already did that, tried redColor for both without success

Comment: I tried your ‘viewForHeaderInSection’ in my project. It works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution:

I have created a lazy loading strong property for each header view I want to display. (luckily there are only three)

Now the views are shown.

It seems that the header views got deallocated without the strong references before the table was rendered.

Could it be that there is a connection to the class implementing the table view delegate and data source protocols is not a UIViewController?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you want to use a custom view, and not the "standard" one ? You may have your reasons, but I don't see anything in your code telling me why :)

I would personally just use this:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) return @"First section header title";
    if (section == 1) return @"Second section header title";
    else return nil;
}
```

Tell me if that's not what you're looking for !

Comment: OK, I may have missed the first line, saying "I want to display a table with custom header titles.". If I'm totally off-topic, I'm sorry :)

Comment: main reasons for me to want to display custom headers are dark backround in the table view and and I want to display an icon in the header. But I don't mind off-topic answers ;)

Comment: Does the 'heightForHeaderInSection' return the correct values ? Have you checked that with a breakpoint ?

Comment: yep, I stepped into the if block and in returns SectionHeaderHeight which is defined as 30. Also, I can see the table with the correct number of rows.

Comment: Can you try "[_myListView bringSubviewToFront: headerView];" after the header view is created ? May be useless, but just to make sure it's not sent behind the table..

Answer (score 0):

Text Color you change it to Black color and check once.

`sectionHeaderTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];`

Comment: The table view background is already dark for black text color, but I tried with blue and still no title visible.

Comment: I Tried with whatever code you have given. simply changed text color it is working fine for me.

Comment: Try giving heightForHeaderInSection as 40 Or any valid value.

Answer (score 0):

you try this code this work on my side :-)

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 24)];

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SectionBackGround.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,24);

    UIImage *imageIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SectionBackGround.png"];
    UIImageView *iconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    iconView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,24);

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 24)];
    label.text = [tableView.dataSource tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];


    [view addSubview:imageView];
    [view addSubview:iconView];
    [view addSubview:label];
    return view;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 24;
}
```